# Calculus problem ε-δ definition

Tags: calculus

Using the  ε-δ definition of the limit, what is the largest value that could serve as δ (when ε=0.1) for the limit statement lim(2x+2)=4 ,x goes to -3

Could you explain what is the  ε-δ definition of the limit? And please explain the problem.

Comment: $$\lim_{x\to-3} 2x + 2 = 2(-3) + 2 = -4 \ne 4$$ Are you sure the question is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to show that $\lim_{x\rightarrow -3}(2x+2) = -4$. It's a test: Someone gives you a small tolerance $\epsilon > 0$, and you have to figure out how to make sure $2x+2$ is within the desired tolerance $\epsilon$ of the $-4$ by restricting $0 < |x-(-3)| < \delta$. So, for every $\epsilon > 0$, you have to come up with some $\delta > 0$. Of course, $\delta$ is going to depend on the $\epsilon$ they give you. If they can give you a small enough $\epsilon > 0$ for which no $\delta$ exists, then the limit equality doesn't hold.

So, someone gives you $\epsilon > 0$ and you have to figure out a way to make sure
$$
       |(2x+2)-(-4)| = |2x+6|=2|x-(-3)| < \epsilon
$$
In this case, choose $\delta = \epsilon/2$. Then, whenever $0 < |x-(-3)| < \delta$, you are guaranteed that $|(2x+2) - (-4)| < \epsilon$. That works regardless of what $0 < \epsilon$ the person gives you. So, $\lim_{x\rightarrow -3}(2x+2)=-4$ as desired.

For $\epsilon = 0.1$, you can guarantee that $|(2x+4)-(-4)|< 0.1$ whenever $0 < |x-(-3)| < 0.05$. They give you $\epsilon=0.1$, and you came up with $\delta=0.05$. Check it on your calculator if you want. Try plugging in numbers strictly between $-3-.05=-3.05$ and $-3+.05=-2.95$ into $2x+2$, and you'll find that the numbers which come out are strictly between $-4-.1=-4.1$ and $-4+.1=-3.9$.